# Looking for a Sci-fi short story about an alien race traveling to a dying star

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, spaceship

I once found a short story on a library computer about an alien race and a dying star. I've been searching for this story since the 9th grade and I've never gotten close to figuring out what it is. It's all of 3-4 paragraphs.

The story is about an intelligent alien race that worships a great star in the sky. One day, they see that their 'God' has begun to shine brightly and the whole civilization rejoices thinking that their 'God' is calling to them. Deciding that they should go to him, the entire planet throws everything they have into building gigantic ships that can travel such a large distance. Once complete, they set off. After many, many years (and on the brink of death, unknown) they finally reach their 'God' only to find out that it wasn't a god at all, just a dying star. As the last being dies, he weeps knowing that his planet is gone and that there was never any god looking out for them.

I could honestly rewrite it with how many times I've reread it in my head but I would really love to read the original, if there is one altogether.

Comment: If you've memorized it (or a part of it), You may be able to Google an exact phrase/sentence to get a result. But, honestly, if it was on a computer and was only a few paragraphs... is it possible a student wrote it as part of an assignment (or for fun)?

The concept sounds a lot like Arthur C. Clarke's "The Star" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_(Clarke_short_story)), although with aliens looking for God, rather than humans looking for aliens.

Comment: Ouch. That hit me right in the feels. Clarke was the man.

Comment: How long ago was 9th grade for you?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be ['If the Stars Are Gods' by Gordon Eklund and Gregory Benford](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/455947.If_the_Stars_Are_Gods)?

In the short story, aliens arrive in earth's solar system to ask humans questions about the sun. It is revealed through conversations with the human scientist that the aliens believe stars are conscious beings and they travel from solar system to solar system, guided by their Priests communing with the stars. The alien's suggest the stars are portals to other dimensions and they are communicating with 'higher-beings'.

Although the short story does not contain every detail you describe it was later expanded to a full length novel. I haven't read the novel so I couldn't say for sure but perhaps that is what you read?

One caveat, form your description you make it seem that the story is being told from the perspective of the aliens whereas the short story is very much the perspective of the human meeting the aliens for the first time.